# jsPdf library, use flex format?

Tags: vue.js, pdf, printing, jspdf

There is functionality for printing coupons in A7 format using the jsPDF library, but when you enter information that exceeds the format, everything is stuck on top of each other. Accordingly, the question is, is it possible to do something like `height:100%` or `fit-content` so that the printing coupon is stretched according to content?

I looked at different formats in the library but didn’t find what I needed.